# FilePulse connect XML reader return file lines instead of structured messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm implementing a file pulse connector that injects data into a topic from an xml. I don't have any error but I get messages in my topic that seems to come from a simple line reader instead of an XML reader:

[image]

Here is my connector settings:

```
{
"name": "xml-connector",
"connector.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",
"fs.listing.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.LocalFSDirectoryListing",
"fs.listing.filters": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.RegexFileListFilter",
"fs.cleanup.policy.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.DeleteCleanupPolicy",
"tasks.file.status.storage.topic": "connect-file-pulse-status",
"task.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.XMLFileInputReader",
"fs.listing.directory.path": "/data/input",
"reader.xml.parser.namespace.aware.enabled": "true",
"fs.scan.interval.ms": "1000",
"errors.log.enable": "false",
"tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers": "broker:9092",
"reader.xml.exclude.empty.elements": "false",
"tasks.file.status.storage.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.state.KafkaFileObjectStateBackingStore",
"tasks.file.status.storage.topic.partitions": "6",
"tasks.file.status.storage.topic.replication.factor": "1",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topic": "xml-calage",
"reader.xml.parser.validating.enabled": "true",
"file.filter.regex.pattern": ".*\\.xml$"
}
```

I expected structured messages like in this tutorial example: https://rmoff.net/2020/10/01/ingesting-xml-data-into-kafka-option-3-kafka-connect-filepulse-connector/

Comment: What converter classes are you using?

Comment: Also, the line breaks can be part of the message. You'll need to actually print the offsets to prove your theory about "line reader" is true

Comment: I didn't know that I have to use a converter class. On differents tutorials there seems to be only the configuration file for the file pulse connector.

Comment: There are default converters in the connect-distributed property file

Comment: Are you talking about those converters ? 
https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/filters/

Comment: Nope. Refer https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs